# Solving multivariable 4 grade equation

Tags: problem-solving, integers

Find the integer solutions of the following equation:

$$8x^4+y^4=6x^2y^2$$

I tried to reconfigure the equation using the notable identity $(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2-2ab$, but due to the numeric coeficients I was not able

Comment: Hint: Can you factor $a^2-6ab+8b^2$? Can you factor $y^4-6x^2y^2+8x^4$?

Comment: It factors into $(2x-y)(2x+y)(\pm \sqrt 2 x -y)(\pm \sqrt 2 x +y)=0$ This means that you can do $y=2x,x\in \Bbb Z$

Also, the fact that the slope of an irrational number means that the $\pm \sqrt 2 x$ cannot have x and y as an integer, just x as an integer only, or y as an integer only on these square root of two branches:


  [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRgQI.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can factor

$8x^4-6x^2y^2+y^4$ as

$9x^4-6x^2y^2+y^4-x^4=(3x^2-y^2)^2-(x^2)^2=(4x^2-y^2)(2x^2-y^2)$

So the equation becomes

$(4x^2-y^2)(2x^2-y^2)=0$

At least one of these two factors has to be equal to 0

But $2x^2=y^2$ is impossible, because doubling a square changes the exponent of $2$ present in the prime factorization of the square from even to odd, which makes it a non-square integer. So:

$4x^2=y^2$

$y=\pm 2x$

The solutions are in the form $(k;\pm2k)$

Comment: Or alternatively, $2x^2 = y^2$ is impossible because it implies $2 = (y/x)^2$, from which follows that $(y/x)$ is either $\sqrt{2}$ or $-\sqrt{2}$.  This is a contradiction because $(y/x)$ is rational.